# Get previous column value if the current column is null in a pivot

Tags: sql-server

I have a data like this:

```
Count | Status | Date
1     | S1     | Jan 2020
5     | S1     | Feb 2020
10    | S1     | Mar 2020
15    | S1     | Apr 2020
1     | S2     | Jan 2020
                          <- feb 2020 is missing for status2
10    | S2     | Mar 2020
                          <- apr 2020 is missing for status2
```

It is basically a cumulative data for each status per month and I needed the dates as column names then group them by status so I need to pivot it.

When I pivot the given data it would look like this:

```
Status | Jan 2020 | Feb 2020 | Mar 2020 | Apr 2020
S1     | 1        | 5        | 10       | 15
S2     | 1        | NULL     | 10       | NULL
```

So what I want is when the column is NULL then it would get the previous column's data, so in this example the data for `Feb 2020` for Status `S2` should be `1` since it is the previous column that has value, also with the `Apr 2020` it should be `10` since it's the previous column with value.

Something like this:

```
Status | Jan 2020 | Feb 2020 | Mar 2020 | Apr 2020
S1     | 1        | 5        | 10       | 15
S2     | 1        | 1 <-     | 10       | 10 <-
```

How can I achieve this one when you pivot a data like this?

Here's a quick sample of what I have so far:

```
--Set the end of the month when getting the @columns variable
DECLARE @toDate DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GETDATE()); 


-- I have a function that gets the 1st month of the year until the month set by @toDate variable to set them as columns in the pivot so it would look like this:
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX)= '[Jan 2020],[Feb 2020],[Mar 2020],[Apr 2020]';


SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        FORMAT(Date, 'MMM yyyy') AS [Date],
        SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY [Status] ORDER BY [Date]) AS [Count],
        [Status]
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Date <= @toDate
    GROUP BY [Date], FORMAT([Date], 'MMM yyyy'), [Status]
) t 
PIVOT(
    MAX(Count)
    for [Date] IN (@columns)
) AS pivot_table;
```

Comment: Do you mind showing us your current pivot query ?

Comment: @Squirrel Added a quick sample of my pivot query

Comment: Isit only ever going to be 4 columns? If so, what's wrong with `COALESCE`/`ISNULL`?

Comment: @Larnu no it will not be, that's why I made the {columns} dynamic since it will need to get the months starting from january to the {toDate} month.

Comment: Then i suggest using a calendar table to get the months, not your table, and getting the data correct in the normalised view. Then you can worry about pivoting it dynamically. Otherwise you'll have an ugly `COALESCE` with 20 columns in it (you don't want that).